# Change URL to shorter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a URL

`http://example.com/test/search.php?id=SearchWord`

And i want to change this into

`http://example.com/test/SearchWord`

Now i tried somethings with .htaccess but i couldn't  get it work because i need to `$_GET['id']`.

I have a if function that checks on `$_GET['id']`.

How do i do this with the new short URL and how to shorten the URL ?

Comment: Have you done any research on this? Looks like you have not.

Comment: How do people get to this page? Is it a target for a search form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ search.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using mod_rewrite in apache.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

This will let you set a RegEx for the requested URL and forward it to a different URL!

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess`, give this a try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /test/search.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: this gives me Not found!